# Scraping a List[Dict] with more dictionaries inside; getting range errors

Tags: python, range, screen-scraping

I have a list of dictionaries that has the information in this picture:

[image]

I'm trying to get into the 'children' list and extract the filesize, filetpye, name, and type (not pictured!). On some of the assets, the children list is empty so I would like to skip those.

I have this loop:

```
children_in_review_link = {}
for i in range(len(items_in_review_link)):
    #pprint.pprint(items_in_review_link[i])
    if items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'] != []:
        review_link_children.append(items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'])
        print(items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'])
        for j in range(len(items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'])):
            children_in_review_link = {
                'child_name': items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'][j]['name'],
                'child_type': items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'][j]['type'],
                'child_size': items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'][j]['filesize'],
                'child_filetype': items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'][j]['filetype'],
            }
            review_link_children.append(children_in_review_link)

pprint.pprint(review_link_children)
```

But I get a "list out of range" error for the line `if items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'] != []:`

I had put in the `pprint.pprint(items_in_review_link[i][0])` line as a check, and it kicks back a "list index out of range" error on the last item in the range.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Maybe start by assigning intermediate results to variables to avoid repeating the same expressions over and over.

Comment: Next, prefer `for x in list_of_things: use(x)` over `for i in range(len(list_of_things)): use(list_of_things[i])`.

Comment: If you also need the index you can also do:
`for i, x in enumerate(list_of_things):   do_something`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that iterables like lists and dicts are *iterable*: you can iterate over their members directly. Using something like

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    do_something(my_list[i])
```

is what's called an anti-pattern. Instead, do

```
for item in my_list:
    do_something(item)
```

This will fix your "List index out of range" errors, because you won't be using a range.

The advice in the comments is also very good: assign `item[0]["asset"]["children"]` to another intermediate variable so you don't have to keep repeating it over and over.

Comment: I'm not sure if this alone will fix any errors, since with `for i in range(len(my_list))`, no `i` should be out of range for `my_list`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 right, I'm not sure where the out of range error is coming from, but my thinking was that if you eliminate the ranges (which are unnecessary anyway), you may get a more intelligible error message for what's actually going wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Trying this today and will update how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

You have used extra [0] . It is not a list of list. Use this code.

```
    children_in_review_link = {}
    for i in range(len(items_in_review_link)):
    #pprint.pprint(items_in_review_link[i])
    if items_in_review_link[i][0]['asset']['children'] != []:
        review_link_children.append(items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'])
        print(items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'])
        for j in range(len(items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'])):
            children_in_review_link = {
                'child_name': items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'][j]['name'],
                'child_type': items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'][j]['type'],
                'child_size': items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'][j]['filesize'],
                'child_filetype': items_in_review_link[i]['asset']['children'][j]['filetype'],
            }
            review_link_children.append(children_in_review_link)

    pprint.pprint(review_link_children)
```

It is always better to use

```
for item in item_list:
   print(item)
```

If you want the index also then use enumerate like this,

```
for i,item in enumerate(item_list):
   print(i,item)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That extra [0] was driving me nuts! Appreciate the guidance!

Comment: No problem bro!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your structure is as shown:

```
results = []
for item in items_in_review_link:
    for child in item['asset']['children']:
        results.append(
            {
                'child_name': child['name'],
                'child_type': child['type'],
                'child_size': child['filesize'],
                'child_filetype': child['filetype']
            }
        )
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
results = [
    {
        'child_name': child['name'],
        'child_type': child['type'],
        'child_size': child['filesize'],
        'child_filetype': child['filetype']
    }
    for item in items_in_review_link
    for child in item['asset']['children']
]
```

In the future you may find it useful to do it one step at a time.

```
for item in items_in_review_link:
    print(item)
```

This lets you act on the result one step at a time instead of trying to solve it all at once.

Additionally, as others have mentioned, whenever you find yourself doing `range(len(some_iterable))`, you're probably doing it the hard way.

One of the nicest things about python is the way `for` loops default to unpacking the iterable into a variable. If your end goal is to access that variable anyway, you're just using more steps in a more obfuscated way.

Comment: Good tip, thanks.